# Codeigniter PHP url segments for users profile

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need it so that when i type in domain.com/user/1 the one gets pulled in as a variable and then can be used to get the correct database values. Right now the variable is set manually with domain.com/user . How do I setup the segments and then make get() that number. I'm working only with username url's as numbers so no, names just domain.com/user/1 , domain.com/user/487 ect

Comment: A code example would be good here, if i understand your problem correctly, a controller class with a function named users would do what you need.  so your URL would look like so: controller/user/(id).

Where you have a function to receive the URL in the controller class like so 'function user($id){ }'

Howver im not sure i understand what your question is, so some code would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at URI Routing: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Something like:

```
$route['user/(:num)'] = "user/user_lookup/$1";
```

in your config/routes.php file will probably do what you'd like.

Comment: @ThomasReggi what do you mean under "what else?" the uri re-routing is the best solution for the problem you drafted in your question.

Comment: like, what other code is there? I put that in.. now what? lol

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand you can pass the segment to your model when you call it in the controller with the URI like this

```
$this->usermode->get_user($this->uri->segment(3));
```

and recieve it in your model like a parameter

```
function get_user($user){
$this->db->where('userid', $user);
$query= $this->db->get('user');

if($query){
return $query->result();
}else{
return false;
}
}
```

I hope i understand correctly what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you could have a user function:

```
function user($id){
    $this->db->where('userid',$id);
    $q = $this->db->get('user');
    $data['userdata']=$q;
    $this->load->view('user_view',$data);
}
```

This will query the `user` table in the database for the `id` passed in the url, and send the results to the `user_view` view. e.g. `http://site.com/user/5` would query for user data that matched the `userid` of 5.